# How does Identity migration determine when to create tables

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-migrations

I've been learning how ASP.NET Identity 2.0 works, and I followed [this tutorial](https://danieleagle.com/2014/05/setting-up-asp-net-identity-framework-2-0-with-database-first-vs2013-update-2-spa-template/) to create a new project and have my database tables get created automatically when I try to log in for the first time.  That all worked, and when I tried to log in, the tables `AspNetRoles`, `AspNetUserClaims`, `AspNetUserLogins`, `AspNetUserRoles` and `AspNetUsers` were created without me having to explicitly run any migrations.

I would like to be able to change the names and/or columns of those tables, so I added this to my `ApplicationDbContext`

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("Users");
}
```

Then when I run my application, I get an exception about the table `Users` not existing.  I dropped the `__MigrationHistory` table from my database to try to get Visual Studio to create my Identity tables again, but it still doesn't create the `Users` table and I get the same error about `Users` not existing.

I got Visual Studio to create the `Users` table by creating a migration and running `Update-Database`, but I don't understand why Visual Studio created the default Identity tables without me running any migrations, but it won't create the `Users` table without me having to explicitly run a migration.  Is there some special logic built in that will only create the Identity tables with the default names, or am I missing something when I mapped `ApplicationUser` to the `Users` table?